# How to change nvim path to .config

Tags: ubuntu, neovim

I just started with this from neovim and ubuntu and I don't know why when I install neovim it is not in .config, putting the command `which nvim` in the terminal tells me that it is in `/ usr / bin / nvim` and to put the configuration I need it to be in .config
Thanks

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be. Try it! Put your `init.vim` in `.config/nvim/` and it'll sure work.

Comment: But I dont't know whyI dont have .config/nvim                                                                 -bash: cd: nvim: No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah it doesn't have to exist by default - you can just create the dictionary yourself (`mkdir .config/nvim`)

Comment: and the folders like vim-plug I also have to add?

Answer (score 5):

## General answer

As @iokanuon mentioned, neovim (and many other applications) doesn't touch your `~/.config/` directory per default. You just need to create the `nvim` directory with

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim
```

and create the `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file like that:

```
echo "echo 'Created init.vim successfully!'" > ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

(or just simply `touch ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`).

## vim-plug

You can give [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) the path where you want to store the plugins as mentioned in the README.md file:

```
" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" ...
call plug#end()
```

So in this case, all plugins are stored in the `~/.vim/plugged` directory. You can adapt it to your needs!

Answer (score 3):

If you install nvim via your package manager, the nvim executable file will be placed in somewhere like `/usr/bin/nvim` or `/usr/local/bin/nvim` based on your system.

The nvim configuration file is named `init.vim`, and it should be put under directory `$HOME/.config/nvim/`. If this directory does not exist, just create it yourself.

```sh
mkdir $HOME/.config/nvim
mv init.vim $HOME/.config/nvim
```